# How to effectively update APISIX route rules

Tags: apache-apisix

I am completely new to [APISIX](https://apisix.apache.org/) and I am following the [getting-started tutorial](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/getting-started/).

The problem is in editing [routes](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/terminology/route/). More specifically, I create a route using [this example](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/getting-started/#create-a-route) of the tutorial and it works as expected. Next I am editing the route's `uri` using:

```
# Please notice the extra 'g' in the uri value 'anythingg' compared to the previous uri
curl "http://127.0.0.1:9080/apisix/admin/routes/1" -H "X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1" -X PATCH -d '
{
  "uri": "/anythingg/*"
}'
```

Then I am trying to connect to the endpoint using the new and the old uri but I am getting an 404 in both cases with different messages! The requests-responses:
**New uri**

```
$ curl -i -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9080/anythingg/foo?arg=10" -H "Host: example.com"
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 233
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 09:13:40 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Server: APISIX/2.15.0

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

**Old uri**

```
$ curl -i -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9080/anything/foo?arg=10" -H "Host: example.com"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 09:13:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: APISIX/2.15.0

{"error_msg":"404 Route Not Found"}
```

How could I update the route rules and get the expected results and what is the cause of the observed behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the new URI indicates that it was returned by httpbin, not APISIX; in the old URI, it was returned by APISIX.

You can update the route in its entirety via the PUT method to ensure it is updated successfully.